# Cancel Boot Camp automatic boot

Tags: uefi, boot-camp, efi

I wanted to install Windows using Boot Camp, I gave it the ISO image and partitioned the disk but decided not to pursue after reboot. Now everytime I power up my MacBook Pro it automatically boots to the installation process.

How do you cancel that ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ever tried to cancel the installation, however I'd believe that the Mac would assume it's installed.

You can [boot to OS X](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH11132?locale=en_US) and use [these instructions](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH17861?locale=en_US) to remove any Windows installation that it believes exists.

To boot to OSX instead of Windows:

> Restart your computer, holding down the Option key until disk icons
>   appear onscreen.
>
> Select the startup disk with the operating system you want to use,
>   then click the arrow below the icon.